# iOSアプリをユーザーに自動アップデートしてもらうには、何かアプリ側で対応は必要でしょうか？

Tags: ios, app-store

現在アプリをストアにアップしてあり、今回バージョンUPを行う予定なのですが、
自動アップデートをONにしているユーザーには確実にアップデートしてもらいたいです。

ストアに新規バージョンをリリースしれば、AppleStoreとiOSで勝手に
自動アップデートしてくれるように見えるのですが、
調べ方が悪いのか公式資料が見つからず詳細がよくわかりませんでした。

自動アップデート設定されている方には漏れなくアップデートしていただきたいので
リリースさえすればアップデートしてもらえるのか、アプリ側で何か対応が必要なのか
ご教授いただきたいです。（公式サイトのリンクでも良いのでお願いします。）

Answer (score 2, accepted):

以下のリンクの通り、基本的には自動的にアップデートされます。
https://support.apple.com/ja-jp/HT202180

ただ、様々な要因で自動でアップデートされない場合があるので、サーバー側APIの変更などへの対応のためにアプリ自体に強制アップデートのための仕組みを実装しておくと良いと思います。
これは、アプリの起動時にバージョンチェックを行って、問題があればAppStore上の自分のアプリを開くように実装するのが一般的です。

以下は自分のアプリを開くための実装方法で、アプリリンクの取得方法なども載っています。
やや古いので必要に応じてリンクを辿って現在のAPIを見たり、Google検索すると良いと思います。
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1629/_index.html